# Just making sure I have this right before I start welding

Tags: batteries, lipo, bms

I have an RC project that requires a 3S battery pack. I am making my own, but want to make sure that I have my cell configuration right before I start spot welding. I am 99% sure this is right, but would rather ask a stupid question, than set fire to my project (and house, equipment, self, etc)
The cells should be a 3S2P 18650 configuration.[image: Top side of pack] [image: Bottom side of pack]

Cheers!

Comment: For future reference, you should flip different images of the same thing only one axis at a time so it is more natural to look at and compare against. As done, the same point moves from the top-left of the screen all the way to the bottom-right. But it looks okay.

Comment: Looks fine. Your balance wires are not drawn in the right order.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Yeah, I realized that I put the order of the balance wires wrong when I posted it, and I'll make the rotation a little more natural if I have to share an image like that in the future. 
Thanks again!

Comment: so, what is the question that you are talking about?

Comment: @jsotola LOL it literally was just me making sure I had the battery cell configuration right for my packs. Like I said, it was a stupid question, but when dealing with LiPo batteries I'd rather as dumb questions than make assumptions. 
Since I am wiring it all to a BMS board, I won't need to wire the balance connection externally, since it will be balanced by the board it's self.

Comment: @JesseKnott you are not understanding ... you did not ask a question

Comment: @jsotola The question is inferred, "I wanted to make sure that I have my cell configuration correct" followed by a series of images of the cells is actually a question...